# How to retrieve JWT token from Azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have the url to call Azure b2c policy. *redirect_uri* points to my application with  response_type=id_token

```
https://xxx.b2clogin.com/qassohomegenius.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SSO_CUSTOM_CHANGEPASSWORD&client_id=xxx4&nonce=xxxe&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fmain%2Fportfolio%2Fsearch&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

Below is the http get request reaching my application with JWT token appended as id_token

*localhost:5001/main/portfolio/search#id_token=eyJhbGci*

What is this **#** symbol in the url??!!  I **can't** get id_token out as http request parameter. How can I read it JWT token out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate the token with <kbd>**openid**</kbd> scope, you will get **ID token** only not access token.

I registered one B2C application and **enabled** below options that are required for implicit flow:

[image]

Now, I ran below authorization request with **`openid`** scope and response type as **id_token** and got same results as you like this:

```
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SUSI&client_id=appId&nonce=1234&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

[image]

> To retrieve the JWT access token from Azure AD B2C, you need to include any **exposed API** permissions in scope.

I created one new **scope** named **`write`** in Expose an API tab of my application:

[image]

Now, I added this permission by granting **admin consent** to it in the application like this:

[image]

To retrieve the JWT access token, I ran below authorization request by changing **scope** and `response_type` to <kbd>**token**</kbd> like this:

```
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SUSI&client_id=appId&nonce=1234&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/<appId>/write openid&response_type=token&prompt=login
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Request an access token in Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens)

**UPDATE:**

To extract the token programmatically, you can make use of below sample Python code:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

# Define the authorization URL
auth_url = "https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SUSI&client_id=appId&nonce=1234&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/appId/write&openid&response_type=token&prompt=login"

# Print the login URL
print("Login URL:", auth_url)

# Send the GET request to the authorization URL
response = requests.get(auth_url)

# Extract the URL from the response headers (assuming it redirects to the login page)
login_url = response.url

# Manually follow the link and paste the redirected URL here
redirected_url = input("Paste the redirected URL here after logging in: ")

# Parse the URL to extract the access token value from the fragment
parsed_url = urlparse(redirected_url)
fragment_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.fragment)

if 'access_token' in fragment_params:
    access_token = fragment_params['access_token'][0]
    print("access_token:", access_token)
else:
    print("access_token not found in response.")
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the difference between them. My original question was how to read the token out in my client application (either id_token or access token) since the URL has # --https://jwt.ms/#id_token=

Comment: Do you mean to extract the value of token from URL using any coding language?

Comment: # symbol in a URL indicates the beginning of the fragment identifier. Are you looking for something like this https://i.imgur.com/d0XqYBo.png?